# Magento date format in advanced search

Tags: php, magento

My version is 1.8.1.0 (Community Edition).

I have a problem with the date format in magento frontend especially in the advanced search.
I have add a custom attribute "event_date" with input type "Date".

Under **Configuration->General** I've set the locale to "France" and under **Configuration->Catalog->Date & Time Custom Options** I've set the **Date Fields Order** to Day/Month/Year.

But when I select a date in frontend with the datepicker in advanced search it adds it in US format. (Month/Day/Year)

What's really strange: The search only works with US format but the search validator expects the date format in d/m/y. I found out that the date format is hardcoded in "app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Advanced/Form.php". If I change it in this file the calendar and validator work in the right format but I get no results because the search still needs the US format.

So what's the best way to force Magento to work in a specified date format?

**UPDATE:**

I also found out, if I set the browser prefered language to en_US the validation works with US (Month/Day/Year) format. So Magento seems to check the client locale and set the date validation to it, but not the date format from calendar or search itself.

**UPDATE 2:**

After I got no response I posted the same question but with a different description under https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16257/date-format-in-advanced-search.

Please have a look there. Finally I could solve 2 of the 3 problems so that my advanced search now runs with en_US date format. The last problem is: Where in code the db query is build for the advanced search and how can I switch to another date format? It seems like en_US date format is hardcoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had similar issue with Date filter :)

The way date time instantiated in the form like that

#### Step 1:-

In Block Form class `Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Advanced_Form`

```
public function getDateInput($attribute, $part = 'from')
{
    $name = $attribute->getAttributeCode() . '[' . $part . ']';
    $value = $this->getAttributeValue($attribute, $part);

    return $this->_getDateBlock()
        ->setName($name)
        ->setId($attribute->getAttributeCode() . ($part == 'from' ? '' : '_' . $part))
        ->setTitle($this->getAttributeLabel($attribute))
        ->setValue($value)
        ->setImage($this->getSkinUrl('images/calendar.gif'))
        ->setFormat('%m/%d/%y') //So you need change the Format here !!!!!
        ->setClass('input-text')
        ->getHtml();
}
```

So you need to change the Date format for the calendar in the line `->setFormat('%m/%d/%y')`

#### ! Take look about the supported datetime format here http://www.dynarch.com/jscal/#sec34

Then its used in the method below to generate the block

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_date');
$this->setData('_select_block', $block);
```

and in that block  class `Mage_Core_Block_Html_Date`

```
Line 40: $displayFormat = Varien_Date::convertZendToStrFtime($this->getFormat(), true, (bool)$this->getTime());
.......
Line53: ifFormat    : "' . $displayFormat . '",
```

---

#### Step 2:-

In the advanced search collection class `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Advanced_Collection`

You need to modify this method to allow the new locale or the new datatime format you needed !

```
Line43: public function addFieldsToFilter($fields) {
.......
.......
.......
.......
Line96: if (!Zend_Date::isDate($conditionValue['from'])) {
.......
Line109:if (!Zend_Date::isDate($conditionValue['to'])) {
.......
}
```

Now You need to modify those 2 lines with the new datetime format you change the search block to allow this method to be validated

For instance i modified the Javascript calendar format to be **%d-%m-%Y** which will produce Date in the calendar like ( **25-12-2014** )

Then i modified The method in the above collection class to be like this

```
if (!Zend_Date::isDate($conditionValue['from'], 'd-m-Y' )) { // I added the format for the validation 
.......
.......
if (!Zend_Date::isDate($conditionValue['to'], 'd-m-Y' )) { // same as above one
```

---

#### step 3:-

Change those value of date inputs in the class `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Advanced_Collection` to whatever format or locale.

Everything works fine with that.

I have made small module that rewrite the 2 classes you need to modify based on the locale you need

Check it out https://github.com/Meabed/magento-advanced-search-datetime-field

Regards !

Comment: If you look at my UPDATE 2 you'll see that I solved exactly these 2 things before. I tried now with `d-m-y` instead of `d/m/y` and voila it works. So with slashes as separator it still doesn't work. You have any clue why?

Comment: I get no error message, I just get no results from advanced search.

Comment: whats the date [to] and [from] ?

Comment: for example `05/02/2014` (setted the date format to `d/m/Y`) I get `No items were found using the following search criteria.` But with `05-02-2014` (setted the date format to `d-m-Y`) it works. By the way: either `d-m-y` or `d/m/y` works. (2 digit year)

Comment: Yes you need convert date according to the locale !
05/02/2014 in US means 02 of May 2014 ! and in EU means 05 of Feb 2014 ! so you need to convert the inputs in class Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Advanced_Collection { $conditionValue['to'],$conditionValue['from'] } then it should work fine

Comment: so somewhere else the en_US date format `m/d/Y` is hardcoded?

Comment: no it should not be ! because here how the datetime generated ``$date= Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($result);`` Can you debug this line with the date you put `` $conditionValue['from'] = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate(null, $conditionValue['from']);`` whats the value of $conditionValue['from'] ?

Comment: if I have `d/m/y` as date format `$conditionValue['from']` is `2014-05-01 23:00:00`!

Comment: it seems to work with `->gmtDate('d/m/y', $conditionValue['from'])` although the output is `01/05/14`

Comment: I'm out of house now. I will accept your answer later.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end I took `d-m-Y` as date format since it's also a common format in france.

Answer (score 0):

This issue struck us before.. and this blog post from Inchoo helped us a lot.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-date-format/

Also, you can look into getting `js/calendar.js` fixed or completely replaced (I recommend the latter suggestion). There's alot of `FIXME` /todo items there that are related to locale and you might want a more modern replacement. Here is a very good and well-made one that we've used for some of our clients: https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Kalendae

`validation.js` for Date however already validates it for the current browser locale as expected. But it can't hurt either to replace it with something like [Abide from Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html).. however this also entails a lot more work in replacing your DOM as it is not a direct replacement.

Comment: I know this blog post but it doesn't really help me because I have magento community version where I don't have the option to "normalize date". Please have a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16257/date-format-in-advanced-search where I post the same question. So my problem is how to get the advanced search in frontend running with different date format than en_US.